# Microsoft Access find field in table with known value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, odbc

We have a fairly large Oracle database that we are able to connect via Microsoft Access and ODBC with read-only access. We work with a front-end system that does not match the structure behind the scenes and often I need to query the system via Microsoft Access. The problem is that we are not provided any documentation as to structure and the structure needs serious attention. Searching for the field that I need is very time consuming.

With our front end, I'm able to view the values that I want to query, and I know the key fields, but I need to find the field that contains the known value.

If I have a record where I know the value of field "A", and have the value of field "X", is it possible to query field "X"?

Front end shows

```
Student ID: 12345678
Payments: 23456
```

Back end

```
TechID: 12345678
???: 23456
```

Can I query "???"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over the collection of tables, and for each table, the collection of fields.

```
Open Database
Get all Tables
For Each Table
   Get all Fields
   For Each Field
       If Field type is text ... and
       If Field size is not TOO Long ...
           Search for string
           If found, write to a results bucket
   Next
Next
```

Here is an example of code for cataloging tables (source [here](http://www.profinvent.com/index.php/ms-office-reports-and-apps?id=97))

```
Public Function GenerateDataDictionary(aDataDictionaryTable As String)
'***       Usage: GenerateDataDictionary("MyDataDictionaryTable")
'*** Extracts the information about the tables for the data dictionary 
'*** and inserts it to a table named aDataDictionaryTable

    Dim tdf As TableDef, fldCur As Field, colTdf As TableDefs
    Dim rstDatadict As Recordset
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Set rstDatadict = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(aDataDictionaryTable)
    Set colTdf = CurrentDb.TableDefs

    'Go through the database and get a tablename   
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    'Do what you want with the table names here.
    rstDatadict.AddNew
    rstDatadict.Update   
rstDatadict.AddNew
    rstDatadict![Table] = tdf.NAME
    rstDatadict![Field] = "----------------------------"
    rstDatadict![Display] = "----------------------------"
    rstDatadict![Type] = ""
    rstDatadict.Update
    rstDatadict.AddNew
    rstDatadict![Table] = "Table Description:"
    For j = 0 To tdf.Properties.Count - 1
          If tdf.Properties(j).NAME = "Description" Then
              rstDatadict![Field] = tdf.Properties(j).Value
          End If
    Next j

    rstDatadict.Update 
    rstDatadict.AddNew
    rstDatadict.Update

For i = 0 To tdf.Fields.Count - 1
          Set fldCur = tdf.Fields(i)          
          rstDatadict.AddNew
          rstDatadict![Table] = tdf.NAME
          rstDatadict![Field] = fldCur.NAME
          rstDatadict![Size] = fldCur.Size

          Select Case fldCur.Type
            Case 1
              FieldDataType = "Yes/No"
            Case 4
              FieldDataType = "Number"
            Case 8
              FieldDataType = "Date"
            Case 10
              FieldDataType = "String"
            Case 11
              FieldDataType = "OLE Object"
            Case 12
              FieldDataType = "Memo"
            Case Else    ' Other values.
              FieldDataType = fldCur.Type
          End Select

          rstDatadict![Type] = FieldDataType                                
                For j = 0 To tdf.Fields(i).Properties.Count - 1
                    If fldCur.Properties(j).NAME = "Description" Then
                        rstDatadict![DESCRIPTION] = fldCur.Properties(j).Value
                    End If

                    If fldCur.Properties(j).NAME = "Caption" Then
                        rstDatadict![Display] = fldCur.Properties(j).Value
                    End If

                    If fldCur.Properties(j).NAME = "Rowsource" Then
                        rstDatadict![LookupSQL] = fldCur.Properties(j).Value
                    End If
                Next j

            rstDatadict.Update

    Next i
    Debug.Print "  " & tdf.NAME
    Next tdf

End Function
```

You can catalog your findings in Access by making a table of field-names which joins to a table of table-names.  Then your searches are based on the catalog instead of raw collections.

I reverse-engineered the schema for MAS 90 (with JobOps add-in) this way.  There's no map, but I had a read-only ODBC connection which I used in precisely the way you propose.  The purchasing accountant would give me a distinctive Product Number and I'd run it through this comprehensive engine.  Over time I succeeded in distilling 700 tables comprising 18k fields down to 20 tables and a few hundred fields.  That allowed us to export our data.

Comment: I tracked down the new link and it should work now.  Congratulations we aren't blind.

Comment: Thanks, S.  I plan to play with this later.  I like `dbAppendOnly` with `OpenRecordset` here.  That option seems to speed up row additions.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is simple.  No, you cannot do that.

There are two solutions that I can think of.  The first is to manually concatenate all the values together and then look for the row that contains the value.  This is imperfect, but might work:

```
select *
from (select t.*, ('|'""col1||'|'||col2+'|' . . .||'|') as allcols
      from t
     ) t
where instr('|23456|', allcols) > 0
```

This would find any row that has that value in a column.  Probably close enough for what you want.

The second is to use UNPIVOT to do essentially the same thing.

I would strongly suggest that you invest a little bit of time to find the mapping between the fields, and then create a view in Oracle that has the field names as seen in the application.  It sounds like this would save you a lot of effort in the medium term.